# Content database more than 350GB with only one site collection

Tags: 2013, 2010, migration, content-database

I just started a project with a customer. They have a content DB in SP2010 that is more than 350 GB and just one site collection (20000 subsites!!!). The Test-SPContentDatabase command did not complete.

But, since we are testing the migration to SP2013, I ran the Mount-SPContentDatabase command, but there is no progress indication which is usually not the case in such scenarios. Please suggest how to approach this huge task.

Answer (score 1):

The subweb count is the problem, here. Even if the subwebs were empty, it would take a significant amount of time to perform the upgrade, likely on the order of days.

Your best solution is to move subwebs to their own Site Collection, even if within the same database (though this would be an opportunity to split them out appropriately across two or more databases).

If using `Export-SPWeb` and `Import-SPWeb` doesn't provide you with the fidelity you require, I would suggest looking into a tool such as Sharegate to perform a content migration between the legacy farm and the new farm.